# Can this $(3-5x)^{\frac{4}{3}}$ be represented in the following form of $(1-y^2)^n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can I force $(3-5x)^{\frac{4}{3}}$ to be in the following form of $(1-y^2)^n$

$n$ must be a rational number

I don't know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: Is there a factor before $(1-y^2)^n$?

Comment: Yeah but I'm mainly trying to see if I can use newton's general binomial theorem to help integrate the function. But would need it in that form before I can use the method I'm familiar with.

Comment: If there is indeed a factor, then it's easy. Just take 3 out of the brackets as $3^{\frac 43}$, and do a substitution $\frac 53 x = y^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Solve for $y$:
$$
(3-5 x)^{4/3}=\left(1-y^2\right)^n
$$

For $n=1$
$$
y = \pm \sqrt{1-(3-5 x)^{4/3}}
$$

For $n=2$
$$
y = \pm \sqrt{1\pm\sqrt{3 \sqrt[3]{3-5 x}-5 \sqrt[3]{3-5 x} x}}
$$

For $n=\frac{1}{3}$
$$
y = \pm \sqrt{5} \sqrt{-125 x^4+300 x^3-270 x^2+108 x-16}
$$

For $n=\frac{4}{3}$
$$
y = \pm \sqrt{5 x-2}
$$